# The sequence issue of AngularJS TypeScript ts files in VS2015 appBundle.js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm learning AngularJS and TypeScript using VS2015 RC Cordova TypeScript project.

I added a "MyController.ts" file in the same folder of "index.ts" with the following code which works well.

```js
module MyTestApp{
   export class MyController
   {
          constructor( $scope )
          {
          $scope.message = { title: "Hello World!!" };
          }
   }
}
var myApp = angular.module( 'myTestApp', [] );         
myApp.controller( 'myController', MyTestApp.MyController );
```

However, when I add another file "YourController.ts" in the same folder of "MyController.ts"

```js
module MyTestApp{
   export class YourController
   {
          constructor( $scope )
          {
          $scope.message = { title: "Hello World!!" };
          }
   }
}
```

and then add this code in the last line of MyController.ts since controller needs to be added in angular module.

```
myApp.controller( 'myController', MyTestApp.YourController);
```

I compiled the project which is ok but ran it with error message.

It turns out that these ts files will all be compiled sequentially into "appBundle.js" with the alphabetical sequence of ts files.
So the cause is that "**Y**ourController.ts" is under "**M**yController.ts" and this line

```
 myApp.controller( 'myController', MyTestApp.YourController);
```

can not find "YourController" which is under the above code in "appBundle.js" file.

I know this is because javascript is a script language which run sequentially and I can cut and paste the following code in "YourController.ts".

```
 var myApp = angular.module( 'myTestApp', [] );
 myApp.controller( 'myController', MyTestApp.MyController );
 myApp.controller( 'myController', MyTestApp.YourController);
```

But what if next time I add another controller, say "**Z**ooController.ts", I should move the all above code in the last line of "**Z**ooController.ts"?

Can anyone suggest me that where is the proper place to place the above code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't recommend using auto bundling as `out` has a few undesirable consequence documented here : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

That said you can use something like `grunt-ts` to mitigate the pain : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#javascript-generation

Comment: thanks for suggestion. but don't know if any setting I can do directly from VS2015.

Comment: Oh. After testing, I figure out that "reference path" in ts file can resolve the sequence issue in "appBundle.js" file.

/// <reference path="controller/BaseController.ts"/>